# Can we change the upload path of niceedit WYSIWYG texteditor

Tags: image-processing, richtextbox, wysiwyg, nicedit

I found [niceedit](http://nicedit.com/) text editor as simple as i wanted. It includes the file upload plugin. It uploads the file to imageshack. I would like to change its upload path. but how don't know. Where can i set the path?

Comment: 1. How is this related to "image-processing"? 2. Would this not be better suited for http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nicUpload plugin for it and changed the upload dir path... :)

Comment: hv u use niceUpload.php or java for your uploading

Comment: I used nicUpload.php for uploading